# app.js shows error: TypeError: Cannot call method 'query' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, pug

I am new to node.js. I am trying to load a csv file values into database. It shows error as follows:

Error:

at
`var stream = client.query(copyFrom('COPY menu_list FROM STDIN'));`

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot call method 'query' of null
>   at /home/sathish/backup2/backup/sappsApli/routes/index.js:487:23
>   at /home/sathish/backup2/backup/sappsApli/node_modules/pg/lib/pool.js:75:25
>   at /home/sathish/backup2/backup/sappsApli/node_modules/pg/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:274:11
>   at /home/sathish/backup2/backup/sappsApli/node_modules/pg/lib/pool.js:27:26
>   at null.<anonymous> (/home/sathish/backup2/backup/sappsApli/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:172:5)
>   at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
>   at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/sathish/backup2/backup/sappsApli/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:109:12)
>   at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
>   at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:710:14)
>   at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
> ```

My code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pg = require('pg');
var copyFrom = require('pg-copy-streams').from;
pg.connect(function(err, client, done) {
    console.log("welcome");
  var stream = client.query(copyFrom('COPY menu_list FROM STDIN'));
  var fileStream = fs.createReadStream('list.csv')
  fileStream.on('error', done);
  fileStream.pipe(stream).on('finish', done).on('error', done);
});
```

Can any body help to crack the issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to pass a connection string to `pg.connect()` if you're not initializing the client with a constructor.

```
var conString = "postgres://username:password@localhost/database";

pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {
    {...}
});
```

Or:

```
var client = new pg.Client(conString);

client.connect(function(error) {
    {...}
});
```

If you checked the error callback, it'd tell you what the problem was.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion,the error rectified ,but my values from csv file is not stored in database can you halp me out